# Return N/A when null from Function that returns INT - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, function, date-range, isnull

I've a Function that I have set to return an INT week number that is calculated from a date passed to the function, Occasionally the function returns NULL, which is what I expect now and again, but instead of wrapping the calling function in ISNULL to return "N/A" how can I do this within function.

Can more than one data type be returned - not more than one at a time - but either INT or Varchar if the returning value is NULL? My scalar function is as below. It creates a temp table of week number (1-4) for a 28 day period from the Last Saturday then use this to return the associated week number of the date passed in to the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[daterangeweeknumber]
(
 -- Add the parameters for the function here

 @refdate datetime

)

RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

-- Run procedure to populate table



-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @weeknumber int
DECLARE @mytemptablevariable table (weeknumber INT,fromdate DATETIME,todate DATETIME)
DECLARE @lastsaturdaydate DATETIME

set @lastsaturdaydate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '18991230', GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, '18991230')

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (1, DATEADD(DAY, -27, @lastsaturdaydate), DATEADD(DAY, -21, @lastsaturdaydate))
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (2, DATEADD(DAY, -20, @lastsaturdaydate), DATEADD(DAY, -14, @lastsaturdaydate))
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (3, DATEADD(DAY, -13, @lastsaturdaydate), DATEADD(DAY, -07, @lastsaturdaydate))
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (4, DATEADD(DAY, -6, @lastsaturdaydate), @lastsaturdaydate)

select @weeknumber = weeknumber
from @mytemptablevariable
where @refdate >= fromdate AND @refdate <= todate

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @weeknumber

END
```

EDIT: And I just realised can't return INT and Varchar to same column (DOH!) and changing return just to varchar would make everything much simpler!

Comment: It really would be cleaner to keep the return value as `NULL` when the value is not applicable and deal with *formatting* that as `N/A` at a much later point.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I totally agree with you. Formatting is a role of a layer which needs to format (tipically a front end). SQL Server should be return the TRUE values of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following wherever you call the function

```
 SELECT ISNULL(CAST(dbo.daterangeweeknumber(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10), 'N/A')
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - I ended up just sticking with returning a varchar value

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your function to return an [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) which can then contain either an `int` or some text, but I'd strongly recommend against it - you'll tend to find yourself tied into knots later trying to deal with this data in a sane fashion - far more than you currently do by just accepting that you have a nullable `int`.